# Maximal-Orthogonal Convex Hull (or Maximal-Rectilinear Convex Hull)

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, computational-geometry, orthogonality

In my research, I have come across a [this paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Lw2jVjh_CXb3BodEZJR0s5Z2c/view?usp=sharing) from the Computational Geometry field and I am not able to understand the concept of Maximal-Rectilinear Convex Hull of a given point set in plane.

In the attached image[image], I have tried to explain my problem.

Edit 1 :
In sketch 4 of attached image, note that the set contains the inside of the rectangle as well and not just the periphery.

Appreciate any help in clearing my confusion.

Comment: The link on the paper is broken.

Comment: its working now. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximal [orthogonal convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_convex_hull) is what is left of the plane when you take away all set-free quadrants, that is basically the intersection of the sets 1,2,3 below plus cutting off the rest outside the rectangle (I have shown only three the most important quadrants on the pictures as the others cannot penetrate in the rectangle, so they make the obvious cut - the same as half-planes). The intersection then is precisely the set drawn on the figure 3 above. In your answer it looks like you are taking away half-planes (less freedom) instead of the quadrants, that's why you get it different. By the way, the inside part of your rectangle seems to be empty. If so, how did you cut it off?[image: Set 1]

[image: Set 2]

[image: Set 3]

Comment: Few questions

1) Maximal orthogonal convex hull is not defined on the Wiki page. It is defined in the paper (linked in question) on page 160, Def 2.4. Are Orthogonal Convex Hull and Maximal-Orthogonal Convex Hull the same?

2) I still don't understand your answer completely. Example, in your image (1), any quadrant that is below and left of the one shown is also set free (i.e none of the three points in quadrant). Do I take a union of all such quads?

3) Why is one of the quadrant case missing? 

Appreciate your help. Don't know why this question was downvoted on Mathoverflow.

Comment: I have updated the paper link. Now its on my google drive in public setting.

Comment: @Abhinav 1) This is the maximal orthogonal convex hull as it defined in your paper. The rectilinear half-plane is the plane without a quadrant. Wiki definition is basically the same (due to Proposition 2.4 in the paper). 2)+3) Yes, you are right, those quadrants are needed too, but I draw only the most important quadrants with non-trivial cut. I have added this explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. One thing is odd in the paper. In def 2.4 it reads, "In Figure 4 the four possible rectilinear half planes are illustrated," But aren't these rectilinear quadrants and not rectilinear half planes?

Comment: @Abhinav They are rectilinear half planes, which are the *complements* of the rectilinear quadrants. The quadrants are white in colour and not in the set.

Comment: I had put the above comment as another question on math.stackexchange [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446700/rectilinear-half-plane-is-my-understanding-correct-image-attached). If you give the above answer there Ill accept it.

Answer (score 1):

After understanding the logic of creating mr-convex hull of a set of points in a plane from A.G's answer, I tried making a sketch that explains the idea clearly (hopefully). You can access the sketch [here](https://sketch.io/render/sketch5604a0533b9e4.png).